# Benefit to running separate endpoints in separate lambdas, if they do the same thing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, versioning, api-design, aws-api-gateway

I'm designing an API with four endpoints.

`/shop/{shop}/payment/{env}/endpoint`

Where `{shops}` can be:

- `alpha-one` (production)
- `alpha-two` (development)
- `alpha-three` (staging)

Where `{env}` can be:

- `test` (keys)
- `live` (keys)

The endpoints are as follows:

1. `/shop/alpha-one/payment/live/endpoint`
2. `/shop/alpha-two/payment/test/endpoint`
3. `/shop/alpha-three/payment/live/endpoint`
4. `/shop/alpha-three/payment/test/endpoint`

I have two options when it comes to using these endpoints in the AWS API Gateway.

Opt 1. I can set each function in the api chain explicitly like this:

- `/shop`

  - `/alpha-one`

    - `/payment`

      - `/live`

        - `/endpoint`

          - `POST` > `my-func-one`
  - `/alpha-two`

    - `/payment`

      - `/live`

        - `/endpoint`

          - `POST` > `my-func-two`
  - `/alpha-three`

    - `/payment`

      - `/live`

        - `/endpoint`

          - `POST` > `my-func-three`
      - `/test`

        - `/endpoint`

          - `POST` > `my-func-four`

Opt 2. Alternatively I can just do this and have the code settle everything out.

- `/shop`

  - `/{shop}`

    - `/payment`

      - `/{env}`

        - `/endpoint`

          - `POST` > `my-func`

Question:

- Is there any benefit to running separate endpoints in separate lambdas? Given that performance and availability for `/shop/alpha-one/payment/live/endpoint` is most important?

Comment: I can think of at least 12 follow up questions as written, and I am honestly not sure which of the 5 questions to answer first. For best result, I would consider you re-write or simplify the question?

Comment: @RodrigoM gotcha, It really only boils down to env vars and different lambdas for each endpoint vs one, but even both of these two things play into each other.

Comment: Ok thanks that helps - I would be happy to start a chat if you like. I have some questions/ideas. Can you setup a chat room and invite? Not sure how that works.

Comment: @RodrigoM Yes, Of course!

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114568/room-for-rodrigo-m-and-thomasreggi?highlights=false

Answer (score 1):

There are benefits to running as separate endpoints. You can set throttle limits on individual resources (alpha-one, alpha-two) and live/test environment separately. You can also do staged deployment (blue/green deployment) by first deploying to the lambda function in test endpoint and then to the live endpoint.